# Generate untrusted server p12 certificate with one click

Tags: certificate

To test some stuff I need to create a bunch of untrusted p12 certificates to be used by untrusted web-server. I read openssl documentation and tried to follow the instructions but the process is very complicated, aggravating and error prone. Is there an easy way (GUI, web application) to get a server certificate with arbitrary subject signed by untrusted, fake CA.

Naked OpenSSL command line tool is not an option because the process is complicated and error-prone. If there is a script that simplifies it I would like to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a script that simplifies it is enough, then:

```
#!/bin/sh

subject="/O=Honest Achmed/OU=Fake Certs/CN=google.com"
file="google"
```

Issue a self-signed certificate (with CA bit enabled):

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -subj "$subject" \
    -x509 -out "$file.pem" -keyout "$file.key" -nodes
```

Issue a CA-signed certificate:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -subj "$subject" \
    -out "$file.csr" -keyout "$file.key" -nodes

openssl x509 -req -in "$file.csr" -out "$file.pem" \
    -CA "$cafile.pem" -CAkey "$cafile.key" -CAserial "serial.txt"
```

Export to PKCS#12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "$file.pem" -inkey "$file.key" -out "$file.p12"
```

Alternative tools are **`certtool`** from GnuTLS and **`hx509`** from Heimdal.

Comment: Thanks it worked (after changing file to cafile in first command)